# Why is the static variable always resetting when I try to implement a singleton pattern for AWSClientFactory in Python?

Tags: python, singleton

I am trying to use a singleton pattern for AWSClientFactory in Python. It looks always the static variable **instance** is reset

```
class AWSClientFactory(object):

    def __new__(cls, profile_name=None):
        if not hasattr(cls, '__instance__') and profile_name is None:
            logging.warning("Row Counter is going to use default profile")
        if not hasattr(cls, '__instance__'):
            cls.__instance__ = super(AWSClientFactory, cls).__new__(cls)
            cls.profile = profile_name
            cls.session = boto3.session.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
        return cls.__instance__

    def get_client(self, api):
        return self.session.client(api)

    def get_resource(self, api):
        return self.session.resource(api)

factory = AWSClientFactory(profile_name=profile_name)
factory1 = AWSClientFactory()
```

I am trying to use singleton pattern for AWSClientFactory in python. It looks alwasy static variable is reset